# What is this 5 pin connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to identify this 5 pin connector. Any ideas?

[image: unidentified connector]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably some variety of JST connector, but it's difficult to tell.

Comment: What is the pin spacing, that would help. Than you compare here: http://www.jst.com/

Comment: It seems to be exactly 1mm pitch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure it's a micro lock by molex:

[image]

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/5041950570/WM10586CT-ND/4879349

[image]

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/5041930500/WM10576-ND/4879322

Comment: You meant to type *micro* lock ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I think this is it. I have ordered some to confirm.

Comment: @MartinF I couldn't figure out what you were talking about because I was also reading it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with laptop2d that it the micro lock by Molex, but here's why.

Initially I thought it was just a basic 5-pin JST connector (with 1mm pitch as you mentioned in your comment), but after seeing the board mounted end of the connector I realized it has a key difference.

[Most JST connectors I've used](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/BM05B-GHS-TBT-LF-SN-N/455-1581-6-ND/1963486,) (there are others, of course) have their connecting tab enter into a separate little slot at the top of board mounted side of the connector. You can see the difference in this image:[image: JST vs. Molex Micro Tab Slot]

Also (at least on Digkey), there were no 1mm pitch 5-pin JST connectors; the smallest I saw started at 1.25mm.